connection is read-timeout thrift.transport
I have installed Hadoop/Hive on GCP VM.
while im connecting hive from remote machine(local machine)couldn't able to connect. But same is connecting from GCP VMs which are in same cluster
Im using sample python script to connect
from pyhive import hive
import logging
import pandas as pd

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
conn = hive.Connection(host="100.34.56.3",port=10000, auth="LDAP", username="test", password="test@111")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("show databases")
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(cursor.fetchall())
print(df)

Getting  below error.
raise TTransportException(type=TTransportException.TIMED_OUT, message="read timeout", inner=e)
thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: read timeout

I would like toconnect from local machine. Please support.
